# Most efficient/easy method for permission system?

Tags: mysql, database-design, bit-manipulation, cakephp-2.3

I'm creating an app using CakePHP and have hit a mental barrier when trying to figure out a permission system for the app. I've narrowed it down to a couple different methods, and I'm looking for some information about which would be a) most easily implemented and b) most efficient (obviously there can be trade-off between these two).

The app has many different models, but for simplification I'll just use User, Department, and Event. I want to be able to individually control CRUD permissions for each user, on each model.

#### Cake ACLs

Though poorly documented, I've got somewhat of an idea of how the ACL system works, and considered creating AROs as follows:

```
[1]user
    create
    read
    update
    delete
[2]department
    ...
```

etc. This would require users being in *many* different groups, and from what I've seen, Cake doesn't easily support this. Is there possibly a better way to do this, or is ACL not suitable for this situation?

#### Permission Flags in DB

This one is pretty straightforward, obviously having a flag in the user's record for
`create_users`, `read_users`, etc. With 4-5 models, this would mean 16-20 fields for permissions, which made me consider either using bit masks, or using a joined table. Is one of these better than the other? Which one is faster with less overhead?

Overall, I guess I really want to know what approach makes the most sense in the scale of the application from an efficiency and ease-of-development standpoint. I'm also open to other suggestions of how to go about this, if you have experience from a past project. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally how I set up permissions - you have `actions` that can be performed, `roles` that can perform those `actions` and `users` who have `roles`.  The examples I've put here are based on what you've requested though I think you'll find it rare you have a user who can do nothing but "create new user records" or "update department records".

```
actions
    id              varchar(50)
    description     varchar(200)

+-------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|    id             | description                                  |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| USER_CREATE       | Allow the user to create USERS records.      |
| USER_DELETE       | Allow the user to delete USERS records.      |
| USER_READ         | Allow the user to read USERS records.        |
| USER_UPDATE       | Allow the user to update USERS records.      |
| DEPARTMENT_CREATE | Allow the user to create DEPARTMENT records. |
| ................. | ............................................ |
+-------------------+----------------------------------------------+

roles
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50)

+----+--------------------+
| id | description        |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Manage users       |
|  2 | Manage departments |
| .. | .................. |
+----+--------------------+

roles_actions
    id              unsigned int(P)
    role_id         unsigned int(F roles.id)
    action_id       varchar(50)(F actions.id)

+----+---------+-------------------+
| id | role_id | action_id         |
+----+---------+-------------------+
|  1 |       1 | USER_CREATE       |
|  2 |       1 | USER_DELETE       |
|  3 |       1 | USER_READ         |
|  4 |       1 | USER_UPDATE       |
|  5 |       2 | DEPARTMENT_CREATE |
|  6 |       2 | DEPARTMENT_DELETE |
| .. | ....... | ................. |
+----+---------+-------------------+

users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    username        varchar(32)(U)
    password        varchar(123) // Hashed, like my potatoes
    ...

+----+----------+----------+-----+
| id | username | password | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | ... |
|  2 | april    | ******** | ... |
|  3 | grant    | ******** | ... |
| .. | ........ | ........ | ... |
+----+----------+----------+-----+

users_roles
    id              unsigned int(P)
    user_id         unsigned int(F users.id)
    role_id         unsigned int(F roles.id)

+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | role_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       2 |       2 |
| .. | ....... | ....... |
+----+---------+---------+
```

To determine if a user has a particular permission you could execute a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( roles_actions.id )
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_roles ON users.id = users_roles.user_id
LEFT JOIN roles_actions ON users_roles.role_id = roles_actions.role_id
WHERE roles_actions.action_id = '<action.id>'
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. If I understand correctly, I'd have to have a role for each possible combination? I agree with what you said with users rarely having just "create" or "delete" permissions. I was having a hard time creating hard "groups" but if I think about the way the app will actually be used, I can simplify it some. Would this work as well where users have multiple roles?

Comment: @Jason - your business rules will determine what roles you need and yes, every user can have as many roles as needed.