# Advice: dilemma in designing typical user-group-relation DB tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I came across this very typical user-group-relation problem in one of my recent projects. Basically, there are several users and groups in the system, and each user may join any group he likes. Currently, I design database tables as following

### Design 1

**[user_table]** id, name, email

**[group_table]** id, name, intro

**[relation_table]** uid, gid

When implementing *"list all users of a given group"* function, it involves at least two tables: relation_table and user_table. To use one db connection as much as possible, I use a JOIN-clause. But the problem is: where should I put this function, userDAO or relationDAO? Since this function involves both tables, it seems to violate *"one DAO for each table"* rule one way or another.

But I have another idea

### Design 2

**[user_group_table]** uid, uname, uemail, gid, gname, gintro

So here's only one combined table, but I can see here that user info and group info are duplicated as more users join groups. And if some column (like gintro: group introduction) is a long text column, won't it increase db size dramatically?

Moreover, if some columns are updatable, won't it be very low efficient to update a group that has thousands of users in it?

How would you guys solve this kind of problems? Really need some advice here!

---

**A follow-up question:**

Assuming I'm using raw JDBC here and have to parse raws into objects in DAOs. So I should at least write *"user rows to user objects"* code once in userDAO. Now if I follow the first design, I would have to write it one more time in relationDAO since I shall have to use column alias to distinct two "name" columns. Most of these two pieces of code are identical but I have to maintain them in two places. Looks a little unwielding to me.

---

**Second follow-up question:**

Now if I have a search function on user table, which uses SQL LIKE-clause on name and email together (sth. like: SELECT * FROM user_table u WHERE u.name LIKE "frog%" OR u.email LIKE "frog%"), and my "evil" P.M. asks me for another *"search users from a given group"* function that behaves the same as the original search function except that only users from a given group are returned. So here again, I'm facing a function involving two tables and part of its logic (the search related clause) is in userDAO. Where should I place this function?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457513/most-efficient-easy-method-for-permission-system/19457931#19457931) might be helpful to you. It was specifically about permissions but the concept of `users` and `groups` and how they are related is part of it. (Your first design is the preferred method)

Comment: @Benny Hill: This is a nice post! I can see the general idea here. Db tables will be more normalized this way. But with so many tables, I'd imagine how complex a query would be to decide a user's permission on a given operation in just one sql query round-trip.

Comment: The query isn't that complex - this is all you need to see if a user has a particular permission: `SELECT COUNT( role_action.id )
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_role ON user.id = user_role.user_id
LEFT JOIN role_action ON user_role.role_id = role_action.role_id
WHERE role_action.action_id = '<action.id>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first design has a higher normalization than your second one.

Both the "list all users in a group" and "list all groups for a user" should go to the **relationDAO**.

This is because you will simply have:

```
public IEnumerable<User> getUsersForGroup(int groupId);
```

and

```
public IEnumerable<Group> getGroupsForUser(int userId);
```

The

> one DAO for each table

rule refers not to this kind of situations, but rather to the fact that you should not have **two** user DAOs for instance.

To summarize, I would go with **the first design**, as it makes more sense in the context of relational database design, and I would place the mentioned query **in the relation DAO**.

Comment: This sounds a reasonable choice to me. But I have two follow-up problems (see the edited post above), would you care to have  a look into it again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @frog Regarding your first follow up question, that might not be the case, as your Relation object *contains* one User object and one Group object. I don't know exactly how you currently deal with your DAOs, but customarily you should have some *models* for your db entities, which you can instantiate. Like instantiate a User, a Group or a Relation. Then you could have something like myRelation.user and myRelation.group to work with. Same could go for follow up question number 2, but as I said, this all depends on your implementation of the data access layer.

Comment: Currently I have userDAO, groupDAO and relationDAO, and yes I have db entities (bean classes) for each of them. But I don't include user or group objects in relation. What I'm doing in my DAO is to send proper sql query and parse results to bean instances. I'm confusing because I thought I should only instantiate user class in userDAO since this is the place where I have the knowledge of the user table. My intension is to separate DAO as much as possible so that when later I alter a table, it will not cause a lot of code changes in different places (or DAOs).